# How to loop vectors when using matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to do a simple loop in matlab. For example, v=[1,2,3], I want to get v(1)=v*2+[1,2,5];V(2)=2*v(1)+[1,2,5], and so on. Then v(1)=[3,6,11]

I have tried:

```
x=[1,2,3];
y=x;
for j=1:5
  y(j+1)=2*y(j)+[1,2,5];
end
```

but is wrong. 
How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried to use A = randi([0 1],100,100), then normalize it, however, it not my expected results.

Comment: Rephrase your question in an understandable way. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
N = 100;
B = rand(N, N);
A = B / norm(B); % substitute norm of your choice
```